# Title and content not stored when sending form data to a DB

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, jpa

When I write a post, the data in the form is not sent to the db, but I don't know what part is the problem.

```
@Entity
@Getter @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Builder @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Account author;

    private String title;

    @Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String content;

    private LocalDateTime publishedDateTime;

    private LocalDateTime modifiedDateTime;

    public void addAuthor(Account account) {
        this.publishedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.author = account;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class PostForm {

    @NotBlank
    @Length(max = 100)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    private String content;
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;
    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @GetMapping("/announcement/write")
    public String newAnnouncementForm(@CurrentAccount Account account, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(account);
        model.addAttribute(new PostForm());
        return "post/form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/announcement/write")
    public String writeNewAnnouncement(@CurrentAccount Account account, @Valid PostForm postForm, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute(account);
            return "post/form";
        }

        Post newPost = postService.createNewPost(modelMapper.map(postForm, Post.class), account);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    public Post createNewPost(Post post, Account account) {
        Post newPost = postRepository.save(post);
        newPost.addAuthor(account);
        return newPost;
    }
}
```

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="fragments.html :: head"></head>
<body>
    <div th:replace="fragments.html :: main-nav"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="py-5 text-center">
            <h2>게시글 작성</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <form class="needs-validation col-sm-8" th:action="@{/announcement/write}" th:object="${postForm}" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">제목</label>
                    <input id="title" type="text" th:field="*{title}" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="제목" aria-describedby="titleHelp" required max="100">
                    <small class="invalid-feedback">제목을 입력하세요.</small>
                    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Title Error</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">내용</label>
                    <textarea id="content" type="textarea" th:field="*{content}" class="form-control"
                              placeholder="내용을 작성해주세요." aria-describedby="contentHelp" required></textarea>
                    <small class="invalid-feedback">내용를 입력하세요.</small>
                    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">Content Error</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" aria-describedby="submitHelp">게시글 작성</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:replace="fragments.html :: footer"></div>
    <script th:replace="fragments.html :: form-validation"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#content').summernote({
                fontNames: ['Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New', 'Noto Sans KR', 'Merriweather'],
                placeholder: '내용을 입력해주세요.',
                tabsize: 2,
                height: 600
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the post creation(게시글 작성) button, I return to the redirect:/ screen, but when I look at the db, id, author, and publishedDateTime are filled in, but the title and content written in post.html are null.
If anyone knows the reason, I would really appreciate it if you could reply.

Comment: Does `th:field="*{content}"` give the field a name?

Comment: Hello! Let's start with the simplest mistake - column names, they overlap, right?

Comment: And maybe you should try `$` instead of `*`?

Comment: sorry. I don't understand give the field a name and column names overlapped.

Comment: I meant database column names with fields with your entity file @Joshep

Comment: I don't know if there are overlapping columns in entity files. Aren't title and content overlapping columns?

Comment: I may have chosen the wrong word. Document has `th:field="*{title}"`, Entity has `title` and in your database column name is `title`. That's what I meant.

Comment: Aha I just solved the problem. Thank you very much for your reply.